# Crashing app when i want to go rootview from other view controller

Tags: iphone

I want to go Root view Controller from another view controller but i got the terminating error. following is the error message in console,

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSCFArray removeObjectsInRange:]: index (4) beyond bounds (1)'
```

This is my code for that

```
NSArray *arr=self.navigationController.viewControllers;
 [self.navigationController popToViewController:[arr objectAtIndex:2] animated:YES];
```

So any one can give me the suggestion on it so can remove the crash

Comment: Are you sure the objectAtIndex: is the RootViewController?

Comment: How can the root be at index 2? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NavigationController has a method called to pop to its root view controller. Maybe you should use this one instead.

```
- (NSArray *)popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

Comment: thanx for your reply but i m not understand how to use it can you please elaborate..

Comment: Replace the 2 lines of code by this : [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]